# autocomplete="off" не работает в Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет.
Как отключить селект с выбором автокомплита в поле пароля?
`autocomplete="off"` не работает в chrome
Так же стоит на форме `autocomplete="off"`. Но безрезультатно.
загуглив, поставил `autocomplete="new-password"` велью не подставляется, но дроп с выбором все равно появляется.
Нужно добиться того, чтобы вообще ни велью, ни дроп с выбором не появлялся.

Помогите, пожалуйста[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В доках указано, что браузер может игнорить настройку, это их прихоть: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password

Comment: Но зачем? Зачем вы хотите усложнить жизнь пользователям?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, вовсе не обязательно усложнить. Знаешь, как задолбало предложение хрома сохранить одноразовый код из смс в качестве нового пароля к сайту (вместо реального пароля, который сохранён)?

Answer (score 2):

Как самый странный вариант: используйте `<textarea>` оформив его как `<input>`.
Однако это будет работать **только для Chromium-браузеров**.

```html
<style>
textarea[name="password"] {
  resize: none;
  -webkit-text-security: disc !important;
}
</style>

<textarea name="password" rows="1">
```

Так же можно использовать стилизованный `<input type="text">` (спасибо @qwertiy за подсказку).
Этот способ будет так же работать **только для Chromium-браузеров**.

```html
<style>
input[name="password"] {
  -webkit-text-security: disc !important;
}
</style>

<input name="password">
```

В обоих случаях можно убрать свойство `-webkit-text-security`, если не нужно прятать вводимые символы.

Comment: А разве на input type=text не сработает?

Comment: @Qwertiy, тоже хороший вариант. Добавил в ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое. Помогло!